# Zeppelin REST API error getting paragraph results - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: impala, apache-zeppelin

From various other StackOverflow posts I understand I can do a Zeppelin API call to run and get the output from a paragraph using the URL:

```
https://[zeppelin url]:[port]/api/notebook/run/[note ID]/[paragraph ID]
```

but this gives me:

```
HTTP ERROR 405
Problem accessing /api/notebook/run/2GG52SU6/2025492809-066545_207456631. Reason:
Method Not Allowed
```

Is there a way of fixing this? Other API calls work fine and the paragraph runs fine in the Zeppelin Web UI (it just does a simple Impala query). I just want to get the output via a REST API so I can call it from an Angular paragraph and manipulate the results before display.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the run paragraph api states it to be a post request ; If you send the get request it will fail with 405 not allowed.

```
    curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/zeppelin/api/notebook/run/2GUEWJDQ4/paragraph_1642773079113_366171993|jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   298  100   298    0     0   2712      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2733
{
  "status": "OK",
  "body": {
    "code": "SUCCESS",
    "msg": [
      {
        "type": "TEXT",
        "data": "common.cmd\ncommon.sh\nfunctions.cmd\nfunctions.sh\ninstall-interpreter.sh\ninterpreter.cmd\ninterpreter.sh\nstop-interpreter.sh\nupgrade-note.sh\nzeppelin-daemon.sh\nzeppelin-systemd-service.sh\nzeppelin.cmd\nzeppelin.sh\n"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```